how to App install in openedx palm version
To install an application in the tutor openedx palm version, I would want to utilize pip. On the OpenEdx Palm version, how can I install any applications? Each and every step specifically defines me. And if any documentation you have plesase send me.

Did you use the Tutor version? Then please refer to this document https://discuss.overhang.io/t/installing-extra-pip-packages/2055
if not, then add your pip package to "OPENEDX_EXTRA_PIP_REQUIREMENTS" of your development.py or production.py files.
